# combining some files using windows powershell

Tags: windows, file, powershell, cat

As an example, I have two files a.txt and b.txt in D drive and I am trying to have content of this files in on file named ab.txt, So I wrote following code in powershell:

```
cd d:\
cat *.txt > d:\ab.txt
```

It worked and combined two files but the problem is that content of a.txt and b.txt files is repeated in ab.txt file many times. for example each source file has just 10 characters but ab.txt file has almost 500 characters.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you run the same command multiple times? Since you'd be `cat`'ing ab.txt too after the first run, it'd get big really quickly. ;^)

Comment: no I did it just once

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(Get-Content -Path *.txt) | Out-File .\ab.txt
```